# Error Connecting to Database PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having problems connecting with a database using a php form. I have created a separate file for php database parameters.

```
<?
$db_username = "username";
$db_password = "password";
$db_name = "db";
$db_host = "host";

?>
```

Include statement

```
include "db_data.php";
```

This is my connection String

```
$dblink =   $Database->connect($db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_host);
```

This is my database class

```
<?php

class Database{

var $dblink;
var $query_error;
var $username;
var $password;
var $host;
var $database;



function connect ($username, $password, $dbname, $host) {
$this->dblink = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);


if($this->dblink == ""){
    echo "Error connecting to database $database<Br>";
    return -1;
  }else{
  return $this->dblink;
  }
 }


 function disconnect(){
   mysql_close($this->dblink);
   }



   }



  ?>
```

I haven't changed any of my connection parameters. Will starting again mysql server solve the problem ??

Thanks Jose

Comment: We can't determine what's wrong if you don't include your database class.

Comment: <?php

class Database{

var $dblink;
var $query_error;
var $username;
var $password;
var $host;
var $database;



function connect($username, $password, $dbname, $host) {
 $this->dblink = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
 

 if($this->dblink == ""){
  echo "Error connecting to database $database<Br>";
  return -1;
  }else{
    return $this->dblink;
  }
}


function disconnect(){
 mysql_close($this->dblink);
}



}



?>     This is my database class  Please Help.... will it help if I restart the service???

Answer (score 0):

A better way to connect to a database is this

```
mysqli_connect("database ip", "database name", "username for database", "password");
```

Try that and place it in a file named connection.php and put the code above in a var like such :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("database ip", "database name", "username for database", "password");
```

Then include the file in your PHP files so there's no need to re-write this in every file

```
Include("connection.php");
```

Comment: Better? How? He could be using that but in a db class?

Comment: For someone starting off it's simpler this way

Comment: If  I use the above code, do I disregard the database class and all the other code and just use the new connection string and include the new "connection.php"

Comment: Yes it's cleaner and simpler

Comment: Thank You I have resolved the problem. The problem was in the IP address of the Host.